# VBA how to create this If IsNumber formula as a function

Tags: excel, vba, function, if-statement

So I am lookingto convert this formula =IF(A3,IF(ISNUMBER(C3/B3),C3/B3,""),"")
into a private function so I can use that instead. I have tried and failed to get it to work in VBA, if it is numeric and it is, how can I perform the division from the two cells?

[image]

Code:

```
Function GetSpendPerHead(Ra As Range, rb As Range, rc As Range) 
    GetSpendPerHead = "" 
    If Ra.Value = True Then
      If IsNumeric(rb.Value) And IsNumeric(rc.Value) Then 
        If rb.Value <> 0 Then
          GetSpendPerHead = rc / rb 
        End If  
      End If 
    End If 
End Function
```

Comment: If you've attempted any code or done any research, including that can be a good way to get extra help as it shows you've attempted to solve the problem yourself.

Does this url help?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/events-worksheetfunctions-shapes/using-excel-worksheet-functions-in-visual-basic

Comment: This is what I have treid but it is just blank:                                                         `Function GetSpendPerHead(Ra As Range, rb As Range, rc As Range)
`GetSpendPerHead = ""
`If Ra.Value = True Then
 `If IsNumeric(rb.Value) And IsNumeric(rc.Value) Then
  `If rb.Value <> 0 Then
  ` GetSpendPerHead = rc / rb
  `End If
 `End If
`End If
`End Function

Comment: Feel free to edit your question with your code rather than trying to put it in the comments. You can use the `{}` button to push it forward 4 spaces and it will format it

Comment: `If Ra.Value > 0 Then`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function seems to work fine for me, here are some test cases.

```
Sub UnitTestGetSpendPerHead()
    
    Dim ra As Range: Set ra = Range("A1")
    Dim rb As Range: Set rb = Range("B1")
    Dim rc As Range: Set rc = Range("C1")
    Dim test As Variant
    rb.NumberFormat = "General"
    
    ' Test 1
    ra.Value2 = ""
    rb.Value2 = 1
    rc.Value2 = 2
    test = GetSpendPerHead(ra, rb, rc)
    Debug.Print "Test 1 Result: " & test
    
    ' Test 2
    ra.Value2 = 2014
    rb.Value2 = 2
    rc.Value2 = "a"
    test = GetSpendPerHead(ra, rb, rc)
    Debug.Print "Test 2 Result: " & test
    
    ' Test 3
    ra.Value2 = 2015
    rb.NumberFormat = "@"
    rb.Value2 = "4"
    rc.Value2 = 2
    test = GetSpendPerHead(ra, rb, rc)
    Debug.Print "Test 3 Result: " & test
End Sub

Function GetSpendPerHead(ra As Range, rb As Range, rc As Range)
    GetSpendPerHead = ""
    If Not IsEmpty(ra.Value) Then
      If IsNumeric(rb.Value) And IsNumeric(rc.Value) Then
        If rb.Value <> 0 Then
          GetSpendPerHead = rc / rb
        End If
      End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: You mean coercion, not concatenation, correct?

Comment: I updated with Not IsEmpty. It was a little hard to determine if OP was just testing with true or understood that was not the way to check whether the cell was empty. 
IF(ISEMPTY()) would have been the correct formula for that interpretation though.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function CheckNumber()

'Define the variables
Dim FirstNumber As Double
Dim SecondNumber As Double
Dim Result As Double

'If we have an error when are reading the variables go to Oops
On Error GoTo Oops
    'Read the first number from row 3 and column 3 (C)
    FirstNumber = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 3).Value
    'Read the first number from row 3 and column 2 (B)
    SecondNumber = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 2).Value
    'Calculate C3/B3
    Result = FirstNumber / SecondNumber
    'Get the result as message box
    MsgBox Result

'If we have error we get this message: Not Number
Oops:
    MsgBox "Not Number"

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, after debugging, problem was instead or Ra.Value = true ,  I then set Ra.Value = 1 and it worked